# publish_actions authentication permission issue

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

The problem with my application is when I test the application as a developer, it ask asks for publish actions permission as it should but when other users go to my application it doesn't ask for publish_actions permission from them.

I added the `publish_actions` permission in application setting, but it's not working. I also tried to include the `publish_actions` permission in the configuration file, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Facebook is never 100% clear about how their API works, and this can be a major source of frustration, I would guess that the issue is that the app will need to be approved before anyone but the developer can accept the publish_actions permission for it.

This page on the Facebook dev site might help: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/opengraph-approval/